# ¿Cómo sumar valores en formulario mediante radio button en PHP?

Tags: php, html, post

Soy principiante en PHP y quiero hacer una especie de "test" en el que ingresas datos mediante un `radio`, al que cada radio le asigno un valor, y al final, ingresas tu peso y altura, internamente, el PHP debería hacer el cálculo del índice de masa corporal y hacer que de acuerdo al resultado, le asigne un valor.

La fórmula del IMC es peso/altura al cuadrado

Al finalizar, debería realizar la suma y si es: menor que 5, saludable, igual o mayor a 5, riesgo alto.

Hasta ahorita no he podido corregir los errores, la función no se realiza y no arroja el resultado.

**diabetes.html**

```
<div>
 <form method="POST" action="resultados.php"> 
 <p>¿Cuántos años tienes? 
    <br /><input type="radio" name="edad[]" value="0"/> 40 años o menos 
    <br /><input type="radio" name="edad[]" value="1"/> 40-49 años
    <br /><input type="radio" name="edad[]" value="2"/> 50-59 años
    <br /><input type="radio" name="edad[]" value="3"/> 60 años o más
    </p>
    <p>¿Tienes familiares directos con diabetes? <br />(Madre, Padre, hermanos o hermanas) 
    <br /><input type="radio" name="familia[]" value="1"/> Sí
    <br /><input type="radio" name="familia[]" value="0"/> No
    </p>
    <p>¿Has sido diagnosticado(a) con presión arterial alta? 
    <br /><input type="radio" name="presion[]" value="1"/> Sí
    <br /><input type="radio" name="presion[]" value="0"/> No
    </p>
    <p>¿Eres físicamente activo(a)? 
    <br /><input type="radio" name="activo[]" value="0"/> Sí
    <br /><input type="radio" name="activo[]" value="1"/> No
    </p>
     <p>¿Eres hombre o mujer? 
    <br /><input type="radio" name="genero[]" value="1"/> Hombre
    <br /><input type="radio" name="genero[]" value="0"/> Mujer
    </p> 
  <p>Si eres mujer: ¿Has sido diagnósticada con diabetes gestacional? 
    <br /><input type="radio" name="gestacional[]" value="1"/> Sí
    <br /><input type="radio" name="gestacional[]" value="0"/> No
    </p>

<p>Ingresa tu peso: <input type="number" name="peso"/>
    </p>
<p>Ingresa tu altura: <input type="number" name="altura"/>
    </p>

    <button type="submit" name="enviar" value="enviar"> Enviar</button>
</form> 
</div>
```

**resultados.php**

```
<?php 
  if(isset($_POST['enviar']))
  {
 $edad = $_POST['edad'];
 $familia = $_POST['familia'];
 $presion = $_POST['presion'];
 $activo = $_POST['activo'];
 $genero = $_POST['genero'];
 $gestacional = $_POST['gestacional'];
 $peso = $_POST['peso'];
 $altura = $_POST['altura'];
 $raltura = $_POST[$altura*$altura];
 $imc = $_POST[$peso/$raltura];
 if($imc <=24){$imc=0;}
 if($imc <=29){$imc=1;}
 if($imc <=39){$imc=2;}
 if($imc >=40){$imc=3;}

    $resultado = $edad+$familia+$presion+$genero+$gestacional+$imc;
    if($resultado <= 5){echo "Saludable";}
    if ($resultado>=5){echo "Riesgo alto";}


    echo "Tu resultado es $resultado";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que cambiar estas lineas:

```
$raltura = $_POST[$altura*$altura];
$imc = $_POST[$peso/$raltura];
```

Por esto:

```
$raltura = $altura*$altura;
$imc = $peso/$raltura;
```

Comment: Con las correcciones, cuando ejecuto el código aparece este mensaje:

Warning: array_sum() expects exactly 1 parameter, 6 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\nvo\pags\test\resultados.php on line 29

Comment: Cual es la linea 29?

Comment: $resultado = array_sum('$edad','$familia','$presion', '$genero', '$gestacional', '$imc');

Comment: Esa linea no esta en tu codigo, pero asi no es como funciona `array_sum`.  Esa funcion solo recibe un parametro que debe de ser un array.  Con el codigo que tienes, no necesitarias esa funcion.